# Cooldown command to check every cooldown (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Alrighty, so, let's say, I want to make a command that takes every cooldown and shows it on an embed. I get the embed part, however, whenever I try to "get" the cooldowns, it just doesn't do anything. I have every map on different js files, which I think it's the issue, but, is there anything I can do so I don't have to rewrite everything on the main file?

Here's some code example for every command with cooldown:

```
const cooldownsdaily= new Map();
const duration = require ('humanize-duration');
```

This is for setting it

```
cooldownsdaily.set(message.author.id, Date.now() + 86400000);
setTimeout(() => cooldownsdaily.delete(message.author.id), 86400000);
```

And this final one is the one I'm currently using to check if it was performed or not, both on the cooldown command and on the daily one

```
const cooldowndaily = cooldownsdaily.get(message.author.id);
if (cooldowndaily) {
        var remainingdaily = duration(cooldowndaily - Date.now(), { units: [`h`,`m`,`s`], language: "es" , round: true})
} if (!cooldowndaily) {
        var remainingdaily = ':white_check_mark:'
}
```

Note: I would be glad if anyone could help me with this, explaining (if there's) the solution so I can learn. I don't want only the code :<, also sorry if the code looks bad, I'm kind of begginer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a cooldown on one specific command, add `let cooldown = new Set();`
and:
`let cdseconds = 30;` to the top of the command, and add this right below that:

```
let cooldownReply = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTitle(message.author.tag + " Slow it down bruh..")
    .setDescription(
      "You're on cooldown! Please wait before using this command again!"
    );
  if (cooldown.has(message.author.id)) {
    message.delete();
    return message.channel.send(cooldownReply);
  }
  cooldown.add(message.author.id);
  setTimeout(() => {
    cooldown.delete(message.author.id);
  }, cdseconds * 1000);
```

This will set a cool down for 30 seconds on the one command. If you want a cooldown for ALL of your commands, simply add: `let cooldown = new Set(); let cdseconds = 30;` to the top, somewhere on line 4-7 if you're not sure. Also make sure to add the embed and stuff that I sent above to all commands too. Sorry if this sounds confusing, please let me know!

Comment: As I said, I'm looking for a general cooldown command and not how to add a cooldown :<, example: https://imgur.com/dUrmUtv

Comment: Oh okay, my bad